# Navigation bar- animate a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a navigation bar with submenu's that slide out when clicked.

So I want to animate a unordered list when another unordered list item is clicked.

So i'm thinking something like: (excluding the CSS)

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="filemenu">File</li>
  <li id="reportmenu">Reports</li>
  <li id="toolsmenu">Tools</li>
  <li id="helpmenu">Help</li>
</ul>

<div class="fileSubmenu">
  <ul class = "fileSubmenu sm">
   <li>New</li>
   <li>Open</li>
   <li>Copy</li>
   <li>Print Setup</li>
   <li>Exit</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#filemenu").click(function () {
           $(".fileSubmenu").animate({left:'50px'});
      });
  });
```

So I would think that the entire 2nd list would slide to the right but it doesn't.

what do the experts suggest?

the basic structure http://jsfiddle.net/zLCWW/2/

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle showing what you have done already? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Do you have any CSS to go with this? Maybe something with some positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#filemenu").click(function () {
        $("div.fileSubmenu").animate({paddingLeft:'50px'});
   });
});
```

because with the left-attribute, you can only modify elements which are `position:relative` or `position:absolute`.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you sir.  So why does there need to be paddinLeft?  Is the left attribute the default if one isn't set?

Comment: The `left`-attribute has no impact on elements positioned as `static`. And a div is per default positioned `static`. There, you always have to use `margin` or `padding`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make your CSS positioning use something other than the default (which is `static`).

### [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QKM2J/)

### CSS:

```
.fileSubmenu {
     position: relative;
}
```

If you have an affliction towards strictly using jQuery:

### jQuery:

```
$('.fileSubmenu').css({'position': 'relative'}).animate({'left': '50px'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great demo on building and animating a slide out nav menu. This is fixed to left side of screen but you can tweak it to your needs.
[Demo](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/30/beautiful-slide-out-navigation-a-css-and-jquery-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zLCWW/8/)

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#menu li").click(function () {
        $( ".fileSubmenu" ).animate({
           width: "70%",
          marginLeft: "50px"
         }, 1500 );
    });
  });
```